# Catching PDF files downloaded through my proxy server

Tags: proxy, https

I need a solution where an https proxy can be configured to stored all PDF files being downloaded by proxy users , with a reasonable way to keep pdf download information (to be precise : download time - client IP - Server domain). I can imagine that one possible solution would be storing the pdf file with this name scheme : %client_ip%-%time_date%-%domain%.pdf.

I may use squid as proxy server but I do not insist on that, I am open to using any proxy server that will do.

Comment: You should update the question to include the technology you will be using in your proxy setup.

Answer (score 2):

Configure squid proxy as a cache server. setup the cache directory writable by squid. And you will good to have the downloaded cache file on your server.